# Jersey JAX-RS: extend logging over resource-class dispatching

Tags: jersey, jax-rs

I am using Jersey JAX-RS for a REST-service.
I a running it in SE-Deployment with GrizzlyHttp inside my programm.

I have also registered a logger that prints out the HTTP-request and the response.

What I am missing is logging "between" the HTTP-server and the resource-class.

I'd like to see log-entries if no path matches or if a path matches but the parameter did not or similar cases. Today I need to check my annotations and compare it to the logged HTTP-parameters. A bit more logging arround that would be helpful.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it by using a **pre-matching** filter.

A pre-matching filter is a filter that gets invoked before the JAR-RS runtime tries to match the request with a resource. This type of filter lets you log the requested URI even though it may not match with any of your resources. You annotate a filter with the `@PreMatching` annotation, and that is all you have to do to have the filter get invoked before the resource matching phase.

**Note:**: *If you want your filter to be discoverable by JAX-RS runtime during the provider scanning phase, then you need to annotate it with the `@Provider` annotation. Alternatively, you can manually register it in your application set-up (as I have done, that's why in the example below I haven't annotated the filter with `@Provider`).*

Here's a very simple example of a pre-matching filter.

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.container.PreMatching;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;
import java.io.IOException;

@PreMatching
public class PreMatchingFilterExample implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    private final static Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(PreMatchingFilterExample.class);
    @Context
    UriInfo uriInfo;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        LOG.info("Resource not found: " + uriInfo.getAbsolutePath());
        LOG.info("Path params: " + uriInfo.getPathParameters());
        LOG.info("Query params: " + uriInfo.getQueryParameters());
    }
}
```